# Chai expect list to contain items of type string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, chai

E.g. this is the list: `lst = ["69.78","","20.60","14.70","8.20","14.20","7.70","15.30"]`

How can I expect `lst` to contain items of type string?

For instance this should fail: `[1,5,2]` and `['5', 2, '1']`

Comment: You can use `.some(a=>typeof a != "string")` in plain js

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I am unit testing with Chai and would therefor like a solution using Chai

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through the array and call [`isString`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_isstring) on each item:

```
const { assert } = require('chai');
lst.forEach(item => assert.isString(item));
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `expect`

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');
lst.forEach(item => expect(item).to.be.a('string'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if any items in not string

```
const notStrings = lst.filter(n => typeof n !== 'string') 
expect(notStrings.length).to.equal(0);
```